# MySQL regular expression matching

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have an array that contains some sting values that need to be matched in a similar fashion to or where. The array looks like this:

```
array('IS','KG','BO BB AF', 'MA')
```

When using a where clause I can match the 1st second and third values

```
SELECT * WHERE product_code LIKE 'IS'
```

but the 3rd value 'BO BB AF' needs to be matched like this

```
SELECT * WHERE product_code LIKE 'BO' or 'BB' or 'AF'
```

Is this possible to do with a single MySQL statement with a regular expression or will I have to break up the string and loop through it?

Comment: your `product_code` column is `varchar` in type and you store values in comma separated form, Am I right?

Comment: Do you want to match exactly `BO BB AF` or only a part of it with `product_code`?

Comment: Only part of it. Matching any of the 2 character codes in the array value to the 2 character code in the DB column. The DB column will always contain only one 2 character code. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXP` operator for such case:

```
SELECT * WHERE product_code REGEXP 'IS|KG|BO|BB|AF|MA';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the feasibility of this query but you can use something like as using `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * WHERE product_code REGEXP 'IS|KG|BO|BB|AF|MA'
```